# How to see shared circles/users of old Google Plus post?

Tags: google-plus, sharing

I want to modify/see the list of shared circles/users of my old posts but I can’t find it anywhere.

[image: Edit this post example]

[image: Your circles example]

Comment: You cannot. You can't even see the Circles that were originally used. At best, you can see the people who can _see_ the post by clicking on the "Limited" link.

Answer (score 2):

That's intentional. Imagine you shared something privately with me, then i commented on it with something that is not meant to be public, thinking that only you and i can see it, then you change the visibility to public and i'm screwed :D.

If you really want to reuse the old post, then you can reshare it with a different visibility. Reshare doesn't tag along the comments, so that's safe.

Comment: Thank you Phong. How about 'seeing the old shared circles`? In your imagination, how can you know you were screwed after I change the shared circles set since you have no way to know which circles I have shared?